# Is it possible to import SAGA colour styles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style, color, saga

iam still using QGIS and SAGA independently in my productive use (despite the excellent SEXTANTE toolbox, which is sometimes a little buggy).
SAGA has some very nice default styles and i am wondering if it is possible to import SAGA color palettes (extension .pal) into QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot import .pal styles into QGIS.

One option would be if SAGA supports the SLD standard. QGIS can import and export SLD.

Comment: sad. I just opened a pal style with an editor and it turns out to be some crazy binary file. Maybe in the future SAGA will support open standards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful, but what I sometimes do is export the grid to a png in SAGA using the *File > Grid > Export > Export Image* tool.
Obviously you can't analyse your data anymore in qgis/arcgis/... but you keep the colors and georeferencing so you can still use it to make a printmap or something.